# Get specific element from each sub array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a common pattern which Im sure there must be a built-in array function in PHP to handle but just can't see it.

I have multiple arrays such as the following:

```
$testArray = array (
    'subArray1' => array(
        'key1' => "Sub array 1 value 1",
        'key2' => "Sub array 1 value 1"
    ),
    'subArray2' => array(
        'key1' => "Sub array 2 value 1",
        'key2' => "Sub array 2 value 2"
    )
);
```

I need to get the `key1` values from each subArray, of which there can be any number.

I always end up just looping over each array to get the required values, but I'm sure there must be an easier, more efficient way to handle this.

I am currently using the following simple foreach to parse the arrays:

```
$preparedSubs = array();

foreach($testArray as $subArray) {
    $preparedSubs[] = $subArray['key1'];
}
```

It's as short as I can make it, but as I said I'm sure there is a PHP construct that would handle this better.

Comment: You want to get the key1 value from each subArray and store it into another array ?

Comment: @Rohan - preferably the value belonging to that key, or both the key and the value together.  Ill post the foreach loop im using currently

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Before PHP 5.5, this would be the most efficient solution:

```
$key = 'key1';

$output = array_map(function($item) use ($key) {
    return $item[$key];
}, $testArray);
```

As of PHP 5.5, there is now an `array_column` function for this (see [COil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28065712/283078)).

Comment: Note: [PHP Closures](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php) are supported from php 5.3, so this method will ok from 5.3 and is not necessary after 5.5

Comment: Below answer works too :) its much simpler Thank you

Comment: This question was asked before PHP 5.5 was released. I updated my question to reflect that when COil's answer was added 3 years later :-)

Answer (score 28):

As of PHP 5.5 you can use the [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function:

```
$key = 'key1';

$testArray = array (
    'subArray1' => array(
        'key1' => "Sub array 1 value 1",
        'key2' => "Sub array 1 value 2"
    ),
    'subArray2' => array(
        'key1' => "Sub array 2 value 1",
        'key2' => "Sub array 2 value 2"
    )
);

$output = array_column($testArray, $key);
var_dump($output);
```

Will output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(19) "Sub array 1 value 1"
  [1]=>
  string(19) "Sub array 2 value 1"
}
```

The only difference with the accepted answer is that you lose the original key name, but I think this is not a problem in your case.

Comment: +1 for the new native function. You could keep the original keys with `array_combine(array_keys($testArray), array_column($testArray, $key))`.