# Filter values from array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to filter the values of `[name]` from the array below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => tags1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => tag2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => tag3
        )
)
```

How to do that?

Comment: What do you mean "filter"?

Comment: PHP version +5.5 ?  -> `array_column()` OR look in the profile of @AbraCadaver for a workaround implementation for php versions under 5.5 :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - get specific element from each sub array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268337/php-get-specific-element-from-each-sub-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for simple solution you can use foreach loop:

```
foreach($array as $row){
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

Comment: That's awesome, thanks. How can I turn the result from the loop into a new array? (all found ['name'] values in one array)

Comment: instead of echo write $result[] = $row['name']. It will append new value to the $result array. Of course before foreach put $result = array();

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get all of the `name` values in an array:

PHP >= 5.5.0 needed for `array_column()` or use the [PHP Implementation of array_column()](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php)

```
$names = array_column($array, 'name');
```

Comment: Thanks, I keep that in mind. Unfortunately, my server runs only 5.3 at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to be able to filter your output array by a particular name?
This function will return an array that only has the subarray that has the matching 'name'

```
function getspecificname($thisarray,$thisname){
    $arraytoreturn=array();
    foreach($thisarray as $onearray){
        if($onearray['name']==$thisname){
            $arraytoreturn[]=$onearray;
        }
    }
    return $arraytoreturn;
}

$myfilteredarray=getspecificname($yourarray,'tag2');
```