# How to push values form a php associative array to jquery array?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I am creating the associative array in `php` in a `loop` like this:

```
$coordinates[] = array("coordinates"=>[$lat, $lng], "site"=>"ext");
$coordinates[] = array("coordinates"=>[$lat, $lng], "site"=>"curr");
```

Which gives:

```
[0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["coordinates"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(18) "40.836132854296686"
      [1]=>
      string(17) "8.404270310882566"
    }
    ["site"]=>
    string(4) "curr"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["coordinates"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "40.8998985"
      [1]=>
      string(9) "9.5177142"
    }
    ["site"]=>
    string(4) "curr"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["coordinates"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(17) "40.71976910000001"
      [1]=>
      string(17) "8.563560499999994"
    }
    ["site"]=>
    string(3) "ext"
  }
}
```

Now I Need to push each **pair** coords eg:

```
["coordinates"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "40.8998985"
      [1]=>
      string(9) "9.5177142"
    }
```

into a `JS` array and do the same for another array with `[site]` values eg:

```
["site"]=>
    string(3) "ext"
```

In `JS` I do:

```
      var coordsJson = '<?php echo json_encode($coordinates); ?>';
      var coords = JSON.parse(coordsJson);
      console.log(coordsJson);
```

And that gives me:

```
[{"coordinates":["40.836132854296686","8.404270310882566"],"site":"curr"},{"coordinates":["40.8998985","9.5177142"],"site":"curr"},{"coordinates":["40.71976910000001","8.563560499999994"],"site":"ext"}]
```

I'd need the `coords` to be a valid array with the pair coords as objects and push `[site]` to an array like `site = []` but I am not sure how to get values form the associative array.

I tried to push

```
myCoords.push(coords['coordinates']);
```

But that's wrong. I believe I should be looping the `json` response but how to `push` to `JS` then?

**UPDATE**

I basically need the js array structured like this:

```
0: (2) ["40.836132854296686", "8.404270310882566"]
1: (2) ["40.8998985", "9.5177142"]
2: (2) ["40.71976910000001", "8.563560499999994"]
```

And have the same but for an array `site[]`, literally looking for **2 arrays** `coords[]` and `site[]`

Comment: I'm having some difficulty in following your explanation. Can you provide an example of how you'd like your data to look in JS once finished? Are you suggesting you want two arrays in JavaScript, one containing all of your 'coordinates' and the other all of your 'site' values?

Comment: @NathanDawson updated the question with the expected result

Comment: @rob.m - so you only need the coordinates part of the php array in the JSON side?

Comment: @pinaki no I need 2 arrays, one for the pair coords ["coordinates"] and one for the ["site"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with arrays in JavaScript is a pleasure when compared to native PHP. You could always use a loop but I'd be inclined to take the functional approach instead.

First, let's simplify moving the data from PHP to JS:

```
var coordsJson = '<?php echo json_encode($coordinates); ?>';
var coords = JSON.parse(coordsJson);
```

You don't need to wrap it in a string and then parse.

```
const coordinates = <?php echo json_encode($coordinates); ?>;
```

I should note that my example is going to be written in ES6.

Next we can use map to build our new arrays containing the data we need.

```
// this could be a one liner but expanding for explanatory purposes.
const coordinatePairs = coordinates.map((coordinate) => {
    // here we're using the spread operator to expand our object.
    // it's a simple way to convert an object into an array.
    return [...coordinate.coordinates];
});
```

Now lets follow a similar, albeit simpler, process for sites.

```
const sites = coordinates.map((coordinate) => (coordinate.site));
```

Comment: oh this is superb, so many things I didn't know eg the spread operator. Thanks a lot Nathan

Comment: I'd like to use ES6, one question when we declare `const` is it considered a `global var`?

Comment: const is a new way of declaring a variable. It means constant so it can't be reassigned unlike the alternative which is let. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Answer (score 1):

Taking from [Get specific element from each sub array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268337/get-specific-element-from-each-sub-array), you need to use array_column to get the specific sub array values.

```
$coords = array_column($coordinates, 'coordinates');
$sites = array_column($coordinates, 'sites');
```

I couldn't test it on my side as I am not on a PC. Please let me know if this works.